# Is there a polar coordinate registers in the let command?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have seen that we ca use `\x1` and `\y1` to access cartesian coordinates of point register `\p1` declared in `let`.

Is there a way to access the polar coordinates (something like `\a1` for the angle and `\r1` for the distance) of the point `\p1`?

If not, what is the best way to do something like this :

```
\draw let \p1=(35:1cm) in (\a1+30,\r1) -- (\a1-30,2*\r1);
```

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there is a direct register for that (and I would love to know too) but you can access that info with a little more work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3,2);
\draw[red,ultra thick] (0,0) -- (35:3cm);
\draw let \p1=(35:3cm), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)} in (0,0) -- (\n2:\n1);
\draw let \p1=(35:1cm), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)} in (0,0) -- (\n2+30:2*\n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

One can further wrap this into a more pragmatic macro but it is not that verbose by itself now. Moreover, you can do the same with respect to another point, I mean it does not need to be the origin that the angle and length measured from.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me and is relatively easy to implement. So may be this is why \a1 and \r1 registers don't need to exist.

Comment: A thanks from me as well, as it helped me solve a problem of my own (I hadn't realized you could do intermediate calculations with `let` like that.).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No problem, it's my pleasure.

Comment: **Note for PGF/TiKz 3 :** From version 3 the arguments of `atan2` are (y,x) in order, and not (x,y). So the code must be adapted.